# Add label function to graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]I'm trying to add the label $y=x^3$ to the graph of the function using `node` but instead of placing it "above right" it appears "below left" for a reason I don't understand

```
\documentclass[preview, border=1.5 pt, convert={size=800x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [xlabel = x, ylabel = y, axis lines=center]
    \addplot [domain=-3:3, smooth] {x^3};
    node [pos=2.9, above right] {$y=x^3$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `pos=` should take a value between 0 (beginning of the path) and 1 (end of the path). Also, if you want the node to be attached to the plot then remove the semicolon at the end of the `\addplot` line. `node` can be its own command if you use `\node`, but then you have to specify its coordinates, not use `pos`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[preview, border=10 pt, convert={size=800x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis} [xlabel = x, ylabel = y, axis lines=center]
                \addplot [domain=-3:3, smooth] {x^3} node[pos=.9,left] {$y=x^3$};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That's ok, thanks. Do you know in addition how can I set the dimension of the image to the dimension of the the axis? So that I don't have a contour around the graph?

Comment: If you comment the third line and cancel 'axis lines=center' you have a contour but not centered axis.